# Proving continuous differentiability over the domain

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem from Tao.

> Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R$ be the function defined by $f(x,y)=\dfrac {xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0):=0$. Show that $f$ is continuously differerentiable.

I have $\dfrac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{y^5 - x^2y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $\dfrac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial{x}} = (0,0)$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.

I am not sure how to proceed with proving continuity, because it seems that the derivative is discontinuous. I am inclined to proceed with $\epsilon-\delta$ definition if possible, but I don't see the point.

Comment: If Tao is right, then the partial derivatives are continuous. Can you **prove** one of them isn't?

Comment: I think you have understood that the problem is at $0$. A simple way to prove (or disprove) continuity here would be to use polar coordinates.

Comment: @nicomezi. That seems like an idea that seems a great approach. Thank you! I took $|sin^5 \theta - cos^5 \theta| \leq 2$ and solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)$ be given by

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}&,(x,y)\ne (0,0)\\\\0&,(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

For $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial  x}&=\frac{y^3(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\\\
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial  y}&=\frac{xy^2(3x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{align}$$

---

Now, note that from the limit definition of the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ we have

$$f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$$

---

We now use the bounds $|x^2-y^2|\le x^2+y^2$, $|x|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $|y|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to establish the estimates

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right|&=\left|\frac{y^3(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\\\
&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}$$

Similarly, we have

$$\left|\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\right|=\left|\frac{x(3x^2y^2+y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\le 3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

---

Can you wrap things up now?

Comment: Thanks @Mark Viola. I can take it from here.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And pleased you have it now.